# binomial tree tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-cd, istgame

HELP ! I am a beginner on LateX and I would like to reproduce this tree by adding the red color on point A and the blue color on the highest point of the tree by enlarging the size of these particular points. Attached is what I have done so far. I thank you in advance for your help. Good day to all !

```
    \tikzset{pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
    \begin{tikzcd}[
    dot/.style={circle, fill, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+3.5pt,
    /utils/exec=\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<4 \rar\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr]\fi},
    /tikz/reddot/.style ={circle, fill=red, minimum size=+12.5pt},
    /tikz/bluedot/.style ={circle, fill=blue, minimum size=+12.5pt},
    /tikz/a/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={above:{#1}}},
    /tikz/ar/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[xshift=+10pt]above:{#1}}},
    /tikz/al/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[xshift=-10pt]above:{#1}}},
    /tikz/arr/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[xshift=+25pt]above:{#1}}},
    /tikz/bb/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[align=center]below:{#1\\ }}},
    /tikz/b/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={below:{#1}}},
    /tikz/bl/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[xshift=-10pt]below:{#1}}},
    /tikz/br/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[xshift=+10pt]below:{#1}}},
    /tikz/brrr/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[xshift=+40pt]below:{#1}}},
    /tikz/bbl/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[align=center, xshift=-10pt]below:{#1\\ }}},
    /tikz/bbr/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[align=center, xshift=+10pt]below:{#1\\ }}},
    /tikz/bbrrr/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[align=center, xshift=+40pt]below:{#1\\ }}},
    /tikz/l/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={ left:{#1}}},
    /tikz/r/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={right:{#1}}},
    arrows={-Stealth},column sep={3cm,between origins}, row sep={1.33cm,between origins},cells={nodes={fill, circle, minimum size=3.5pt, inner sep=0pt, font=\large}}]
                &   &   & |[bluedot, ar=70.00, br=70.00, bbr=0.00]| \\
                &   & |[a=62.99, b=62.99, bb=3.36]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &  \\
                & |[a=56.12, b=56.12, bb=4.68]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &   & |[arr=56.12, br=62.99, bbr=6.87,brrr=56.12, bbrrr=0.00]| \\
        |[al=50.00, bl=50.00, bbl=5.47]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &  & |[reddot, a=50.00, bl=56.12, bbl=6.12, br=50.00, bbr=2.66]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] & \\                            
                & |[a=44.55, b=50.00, bb=6.38]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &   & |[arr=44.55, br=56.12, bbr=11.57, brrr=50.00, bbrrr=5.45]| \\
                &   & |[a=39.69, b=50.00, bb=10.31]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &  \\
                &   &   & |[ar=35.36, br=50.00, bbr=14.64]|           
    \end{tikzcd} 

    \begin{tikzcd}[
    dot/.style={circle, fill, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+3.5pt,
    /utils/exec=\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<4 \rar\urar\drar\fi},
    /tikz/a/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={above:{#1}}},
    /tikz/al/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[xshift=-10pt]above:{#1}}},
    /tikz/bb/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[align=center]below:{#1\\second line}}},
    /tikz/b/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={below:{#1}}},
    /tikz/bl/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[xshift=-10pt]below:{#1}}},
    /tikz/bbl/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[align=center, xshift=-10pt]below:{#1\\second line}}},
    /tikz/bbr/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={[align=center]below right:{#1\\second line}}},
    /tikz/l/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={ left:{#1}}},
    /tikz/r/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={right:{#1}}},
    arrows={-Stealth},column sep={3cm,between origins}, row sep={1.33cm,between origins},cells={nodes={fill, circle, minimum size=3.5pt, inner sep=0pt, font=\large}}]
                &                                  &                                      & |[fill=blue,minimum size=12.5,"70.70" above right,"70.70" below right, "0.00" below right]| \\
                &                                  & |["62.99" above,"62.99" below, "3.36" below]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &  \\
                & |[a=56.12, b=56.12, bb=4.68]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &                                      & |["56.12" above right,"62.99" below left,"6.87" below left, "56.12" below right,"0.00" below right]| \\
        |[al=50.00, bl=50.00, bbl=5.47]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &             & |[fill=red,minimum size=12.5,"50.00" above,"56.12" below left,"6.12" below left, "50.00" below right,"2.66" below right]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr]      & \\                            
                & |["44.55" above,"50.00" below, "6.38" below]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &                                      & |["44.55" above right,"56.12" below left,"11.57" below left, "50.00" below right,"5.45" below right]| \\
                &                                  & |["39.69" above,"50.00" below, "10.31" below]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &  \\
                &                                  &                                      & |["35.36" above right,"50.00" below right, "14.64" below right]|           
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image: american lookback pricing tree]

Comment: I am a beginner on LateX and I would like to reproduce this tree by adding the red color on point A and the blue color on the highest point of the tree by enlarging the size of these particular points. Attached is what I have done so far. I thank you in advance for your help. Good day to all !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can always edit your question by clicking on the "Edit" button if you want to provide more information to it.

Comment: Welcome @Arthur. // I moved your comment to the question, as it's a good statement. So your comment is obsolete now :)

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565525/binomial-tree-using-tikz/565550#565550 can help you. To the showed tree you can easy add labels and desired colors.

Comment: What is your complete tex code? You have put only a fragment.

Comment: This looks like an adaption of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/674354).

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

The enlarged color points are plotted using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}   % for enlarged color points (\tzdot*)
\usepackage{istgame}  % to draw tree
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\setistgrowdirection'{east}
\setxtshowmidarrows<.95>
\xtShowMidArrows
\xtShowEndPoints
\xtdistance{40mm}{30mm}
\istroot(0)<180>{\makecell[r]{50.00\\50.00\\5.47}}
  \istb \istb \endist
\istroot(a1)(0-1)<90>{56.12}
  \istb \istb \endist
  \xtOwner(a1){\makecell[r]{56.12\\4.68}}[below=3pt]
\istroot(a2)(0-2)<90>{44.55}
  \istb \istb \endist
  \xtOwner(a2){\makecell[r]{50.00\\6.38}}[below]
\istroot(b1)(a1-1){62.99}
  \istb{}{\makecell[r]{70.0\\70.0\\0.0}}
  \istb{}{\makecell[c]{56.12\\
            62.99\quad 56.12\\
            \hphantom{0}6.87\quad \hphantom{0}0.00}
         }
  \endist
  \xtOwner(b1){\makecell[r]{62.99\\3.36}}[below]

\istroot(b2)(a1-2){50.00}
  \istb \istb \endist
  \xtOwner(b2){\makecell[r]{56.12\quad 50.00\\
               \hphantom{0}6.12\quad
               \hphantom{0}2.66}
              }[below=7pt]
\istroot(b3)(a2-1)<0>{\quad A}
  \istb \istb \endist
\istroot(b4)(a2-2){39.69}
  \istb{}{\makecell[c]{44.55\\
            56.12\quad 50.00\\
            11.57\quad \hphantom{0}5.47}
         }
  \istb{}{\makecell[r]{35.36\\50.00\\14.64}}
  \endist
  \xtOwner(b4){\makecell[r]{50.00\\10.31}}[below]

%% points using the "tzplot" package:
\tzdot*[red](b3)(5pt)    % red point,  size=5pt
\tzdot*[blue](b1-1)(5pt) % blue point, size=5pt

\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `tikz-cd` may not be the right tool for this. I suggest plain `tikz`. Here is one way to do this:

You can use the `positioning` library to place your nodes precisely so they will not be affected by the labels.

Setting the `dot` style with a color parameter can be done in a `tikzset`:

```
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={draw, #1, fill=#1, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt},
    dot/.default={black}
}
```

Then the code to place the nodes would look like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={dot}, node distance=1cm and 3cm]
\node(A){};
\node[above right=of A](B1){};
\node[below right=of A](B2){};
\node[above right=of B1](C1){};
\node[below right=of B1, dot=red](C2){};
\node[below right=of B2](C3){};
\node[above right=of C1, dot=blue](D1){};
\node[below right=of C1](D2){};
\node[above right=of C3](D3){};
\node[below right=of C3](D4){};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Next we can draw the arrows. You have a specific kind of arrow in your diagram. The shape is `Stealth` and it's not quite at the end of the line. You can do this using `decorations.markings` and `arrows.meta`. Add to your `tikzset`:

```
arrowmark/.style={postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .9 with {\arrow{Stealth}}}}}
```

Then the `\draw` command with option `arrowmark` can draw your arrows:

```
\draw[arrowmark](A)--(B1); \draw[arrowmark](A)--(B2);
\draw[arrowmark](B1)--(C1); \draw[arrowmark](B1)--(C2);
\draw[arrowmark](B2)--(C2); \draw[arrowmark](B2)--(C3);
\draw[arrowmark](C1)--(D1); \draw[arrowmark](C1)--(D2);
\draw[arrowmark](C2)--(D2); \draw[arrowmark](C2)--(D3);
\draw[arrowmark](C3)--(D3); \draw[arrowmark](C3)--(D4);
```

[image]

Labels can be added to the nodes using `label={[<options>]<direction>:<contents>}`. You can use angles for directions if you wish and you can change `label distance` as an option. You can add more than one label to a node. Multiple-line labels are allowed using `\\` to separate lines if you add `align=right` (or any alignment) to your options. So your first few nodes would look like:

```
\node[label={left:50.00\\50.00\\5.47}](A){};
\node[above right=of A, label={below:56.12\\4.68}, label={above:56.12}](B1){};
\node[below right=of A, label={below:50.00\\6.38}, label={above:44.55}](B2){};
```

[image]

Here is the complete code. I added a "phantom digit" command `\phdi` to get the spacing right on the far-right labels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={draw, #1, fill=#1, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt},
    dot/.default={black},
    arrowmark/.style={postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .9 with {\arrow{Stealth}}}}}
}
\newcommand{\phdi}{\phantom{0}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={dot}, node distance=1cm and 3cm, align=right, font=\scriptsize]
\node[label={left:50.00\\50.00\\5.47}](A){};
\node[above right=of A, label={below:56.12\\4.68}, label={above:56.12}](B1){};
\node[below right=of A, label={below:50.00\\6.38}, label={above:44.55}](B2){};
\node[above right=of B1, label={below:62.99\\3.36}, label={above:62.99}](C1){};
\node[below right=of B1, dot=red, label={[label distance=2.5mm]-120:56.12\\6.12}, label={[label distance=2.5mm]-60:50.00\\2.66}, label={above:50.00}, label={[label distance=2.5mm]right:A}](C2){};
\node[below right=of B2, label={below:50.00\\10.31}, label={above:39.69}](C3){};
\node[above right=of C1, dot=blue, label={right:70.00\\70.00\\0.00}](D1){};
\node[below right=of C1, label={[align=center]right:56.12\\62.99\quad56.12\\\phdi6.87\quad\phdi0.00}](D2){};
\node[above right=of C3, label={[align=center]right:44.55\\56.12\quad50.00\\11.57\quad\phdi5.45}](D3){};
\node[below right=of C3, label={right:35.36\\50.00\\14.64}](D4){};
\draw[arrowmark](A)--(B1); \draw[arrowmark](A)--(B2);
\draw[arrowmark](B1)--(C1); \draw[arrowmark](B1)--(C2);
\draw[arrowmark](B2)--(C2); \draw[arrowmark](B2)--(C3);
\draw[arrowmark](C1)--(D1); \draw[arrowmark](C1)--(D2);
\draw[arrowmark](C2)--(D2); \draw[arrowmark](C2)--(D3);
\draw[arrowmark](C3)--(D3); \draw[arrowmark](C3)--(D4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [my similar answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/674354), however instead of a bunch of keys that produce a various labels I'm using the `quotes` library which uses a very specifical “d label” (d as in direction?) is to be used which puts its content into a `tabular` environment.

The keys `^`, `v`, `<` and `>` are setup so that they stand for `above`, `below`, `left` and `right` but their value specifies the number of columns in the `tabular` environment.

It's a bit messy with `&` acting as active version for the underlying TikZ matrix and also as the normal `&` (catcode 4), this works if `ampersand replacement` is *not* used.

The `siunitx` package doesn't like an active `&` either, I had to resort to the basic `r` column.

---

It's not clear what you mean by

> the highest point of the tree

so I just made the A point red.

If you need one points to be bigger you can use `minimum size` just with that point and use a bigger value than `3.5pt` (which is used here in the options of the `tikzcd` environment). Making a dot blue shouldn't be a problem either.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, quotes}
\makeatletter
\def\amp@normal{&}{\catcode`\&=13 \gdef\makeactiveampersandnormal{\let&\amp@normal}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down, code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>,
  @create d label/n/.initial=1,
  quotes mean d label/.style={
    node quotes mean={
      label={[every d label,create d label shortcuts,##2]\makeactiveampersandnormal\setlength\tabcolsep{.5\tabcolsep}%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}*{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@create d label/n}}{r}@{}}##1\end{tabular}}}},
  create d label shortcuts/.style={
    ^/.style={label position=90, @create d label/n/.expanded={##1}},^/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@create d label/n},
    v/.style={label position=-90,@create d label/n/.expanded={##1}},v/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@create d label/n},
    </.style={label position=180,@create d label/n/.expanded={##1}},>/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@create d label/n},
    >/.style={label position=0,  @create d label/n/.expanded={##1}},</.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@create d label/n}},
  every d label/.style={rectangle, inner sep=+0pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  /tikz/dot/.style={circle, fill, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+3.5pt,
    /utils/exec=\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<4 \urar\drar\fi},
  arrows={-, /tikz/every to/.append style={edge node={pic[pos=.95]{arrow=Stealth}}}},
  cells={nodes={dot, quotes mean d label}},
  column sep={3cm,between origins}, row sep={1.5cm,between origins},
  label distance=2ex,
]
  & & & |["70.00 \\ 70.00 \\ 0.00" >]| \\
  & & |["62.99" ^, "62.99 \\ 3.36" v]| \\
  & |["56.12" ^, "56.12 \\ 4.68" v]|
    & & |["\mc{56.12} \\ 62.99 & 56.12 \\ 6.87 & 0.00" >=2]| \\
|["50.00 \\ 50.00 \\ 5.47" <]|
  & & |["50.00"^, "56.12 & 50.00 \\ 6.12 & 2.66" {v=2, below=1ex}, label=right:A, red]| \\
  & |["44.55"^, "50.00 \\ 6.38" v]|
    & & |["\mc{44.55} \\ 56.12 & 50.00 \\ 11.57 & 5.45" >=2]| \\
  & & |["36.69"^, "50.00 \\ 10.31" v]| \\
  & & & |["33.36 \\ 50.00 \\ 14.65" >]|
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]